# RMarkdown / pandoc fails to knit Pdf with latex color commands

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

- Mac Os: 10.11.6
- R version: 3.3.1
- MacTex: 2016 / TexLive: 6.2.2
- RMarkdown: 1.0.9014
- Knitr: 1.14
- Pandoc: 1.17

RMarkdown fails to knit PDF when latex commands such as:

```
\textcolor{blue}{Character String}
```

are present in the .rmd file. The error output is:

> /usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.pdf --template ~/R/3.3/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
>   ! Undefined control sequence.
>   l.105 \textcolor
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>
> Execution halted

Inclusion of an r code chunk with echo = TRUE such as:

````
```{r, echo = TRUE}
# I am a glitch 
```
````

in the .rmd file allows for the successful creation of the PDF document.

If all r code chunks in the .rmd file are set with echo = FALSE or equivalent statements, the PDF file will not knit regardless of latex engine used if latex commands such as /textcolor are present. If only latex commands such as \begin{tabular}, *many*, etc… are used the error is not present.

Comment: Could you share the YAML header from your file?

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530362/rstudio-knitr-failed-to-convert-rmd-to-pdf-windows-7/39530540#39530540

Answer (score 6):

Addition of **“header-includes: \usepackage{color}”** to the YAML header, as seen below, addresses the issue. However, it is unclear why insertion of an **“echo = TRUE”** R-code chunk also resolves the issue.

```
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: \usepackage{color}
---
```

Interestingly, with a previous version of the R-Studio suite, as see below, inclusion of **“header-includes: \usepackage{color}”** in the YAML header, did not appear necessary prior to use of commands such as **"\textcolor{blue}{Character String}"** in the .rmd file.

- Mac OS: 10.10.5
- R Version: 3.2.2
- MacTex: 2014 / TexLive: 6.2.0
- Rmarkdown: 1.0
- Knitr: 1.13
- Pandoc: 1.13.1

Comment: I am utilizing a header.tex in my `header-includes:` section. Adding `\usepackage{color}` into that file solved my issues. Thank you.